# Passing URL parameters to Controller but NOT displayed in URL

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, request, parameter-passing

I have a search page where I search for list of employees based on some criteria and once the employee list is displayed, I click on one of the Employee name to view the employee details.The search result is displayed in a tabular format and includes Employee Name(only the first name),Employee Id and Full Name of the employee.Employee ID and Full Name are read only.

In my code, when i click on the Employee Name, I should get additional details of the employee via the employee id as shown below:

**employee.jsp**

```
<A HREF="${ctx}/employeeProfile/employeeDetail.do?employeeID="${employeeProfile.employeeID}"&fullName=${employeeProfile.fullName}">Employee Name</A>
```

**EmployeeDetailController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employeeDetail.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView employeeDetail(@RequestParam(value = "employeeID") final String employeeID,
        @RequestParam(value = "fullName") final String fullName, final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response, final ModelMap modelMap) throws Exception {
```

As a part of security test, i need to remove the employeeID and fullName from the URL as it exposes the employee data.

Can anybody suggest how to pass the request parameters to the controller class in such a way that the parameters are not visible in URL i:e expected URL should be **${ctx}/employeeProfile/employeeDetail.do?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure whether you can remove all the data from url but you can try to encrypt the data in the url. And then you can decrypt it in the controller class.

Comment: Don't use a link use a form with a POST which encoded the data in the body.

Comment: You can do it by changing the request to a POST request, but you're doing it wrong. Your design is wrong, you should use GET method not POST for a job like this.

Comment: Indeed. Just don't pass the employee name. This makes indeed no sense. You can easily obtain it based on passed-in employee ID. The security concern won't be solved by switching GET to POST. It will only be solved by checking on every request if the currently logged-in/active user is allowed to perform the request.

Comment: @M.Deinum I cannot use POST method here as i am getting the details of an employee.It has to be GET method.

Comment: And why wouldn't that be possible. Post the id, put the information in flash scope, redirect to the display method and bingo. Not saying that that is the best approach but if you aren't allowed to put things into your URL that is one of the few options you have.

Comment: @BalusC the security concern is about the information in the URL not if someone can see the information or not (as explained by the OP). Although I agree that adding the full name to the URL doesn't make sense.

Comment: @M.Deinum: even with POST, the employee ID is visible to enduser in some way (HTML source code, HTTP traffic). So the security concern is moot. Knowing or sharing own one absolutely can't be a security concern. Guessing someone else's one, manipulating the HTML source and/or HTTP traffic and successfully seeing all its associated data definitely is. But for that other solution has to be used (as pointed out in my previous comment).

Comment: @BalusC I don't say I disagree with you but for some reason the security officer at that place thinks that hidding it from the URL is a must. encryption will only add a layer of indirection (imho) so one has to really implement security. But that wasn't the question :)